# Node weighted Steiner Tree Problem where all Nodes have the same Weight

Tags: graphs, trees, np

The node weighted Steiner Tree Problem as found in [this compendium](https://theory.cs.uni-bonn.de/info5/steinerkompendium/netcompendium.pdf):

$\textbf{Instance}: \text{Graph } G = (V, E)\text{, set of terminals } S \subseteq V \text{ and a node weight function } w:V \to \mathbb{R}^+$
$\textbf{Solution}: \text{A tree } T = (V_T,E_T) \text{ in } G \text{, such that } S\subseteq V_T \subseteq V,~E_T \subseteq E.$
$\textbf{Objective}: \text{Minimize the sum of the vertices weight}$

Is NP hard. But what if all nodes have the same weight? So the weight function $w$ is just a constant function that maps to 1 for all Vertices: $\forall v \in V:w(v) = 1$

Is there a name for this Problem? Is it NP hard? If yes what algorithms can I use for  approximation?

Please note that this problem is not equals MST, ShortestPath or TSP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all vertex weights are equal, minimizing $\sum_{v \in V_T} w(v)$ is equivalent to minimizing $|V_T|$, and since a tree on $x$ vertices has exactly $x-1$, edges, this is equivalent to minimizing $|E_T|$.

Therefore your problem [is NP-hard](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19477/steiner-tree-problem-for-unweighted-graphs).

Moreover, any $\alpha$-approximation algorithm for the classical Steiner tree problem, where $\alpha$ is a constant, can also be used to provide a $\alpha$-approximation for your version. Let $v$ be a terminal and let $\overline{w}$ be the (constant) vertex weight. Add a new vertex $v'$ and the edge $(v, v')$. Then drop all vertex weights, and set all edge weights to $\overline{w}$.

You are left with an instance of Steiner tree such that any solution to this instance can be converted to a solution for your version of the problem having the same cost (by simply deleting $(v,v')$ from $T_V$), and vice-versa (by adding $(v,v')$ to $T_V$).